# Deploying nextjs fronend and nodejs backend on heroku Error

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, next.js, deployment

I am trying to deploy this app which has the directory :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FGoxM.png)

I added a procfile. But when i try to push it to master using commands:
`heroku git:remote -a pet-finder-1`
`git add .`
`git commit -m "deply`
`git push heroku master`

it gives me error:

```
 HINT: This occurs when Heroku cannot detect the buildpack to use for this application automatically.
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/pet-finder-1.git'
```

I have tried setting build package using these command:
`heroku buildpacks:set heroku/nodejs -a pet-finder-1`
but none worked

**Update:**

after setting the buildpacks and creating a package.json at root using

```
npm init -y
```

I got these new errors:

```
2023-10-12T14:37:35.857549+00:00 app[web.1]: TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The first argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer, ArrayBuffer, or Array or an Array-like Object. Received undefined
2023-10-12T14:37:35.857551+00:00 app[web.1]: at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:405:5)
2023-10-12T14:37:35.857551+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.from (node:buffer:333:9)
2023-10-12T14:37:35.857551+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.<anonymous> (/app/server/apis/upload.js:53:26)
2023-10-12T14:37:35.857552+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1256:14)
2023-10-12T14:37:35.857553+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1310:10)
2023-10-12T14:37:35.857553+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1119:32)
2023-10-12T14:37:35.857553+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:960:12)
2023-10-12T14:37:35.857553+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1143:19)
2023-10-12T14:37:35.857554+00:00 app[web.1]: at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:119:18)
2023-10-12T14:37:35.857554+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.<anonymous> (/app/server/server.js:10:16) {
2023-10-12T14:37:35.857558+00:00 app[web.1]: code: 'ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE'
2023-10-12T14:37:35.857558+00:00 app[web.1]: }
2023-10-12T14:37:35.857558+00:00 app[web.1]:
2023-10-12T14:37:35.857562+00:00 app[web.1]: Node.js v18.18.1
2023-10-12T14:37:35.864610+00:00 app[web.1]: npm notice
2023-10-12T14:37:35.864656+00:00 app[web.1]: npm notice New major version of npm available! 9.8.1 -> 10.2.0
2023-10-12T14:37:35.864812+00:00 app[web.1]: npm notice Changelog: <https://github.com/npm/cli/releases/tag/v10.2.0>
2023-10-12T14:37:35.864836+00:00 app[web.1]: npm notice Run `npm install -g npm@10.2.0` to update!
2023-10-12T14:37:35.864909+00:00 app[web.1]: npm notice
2023-10-12T14:37:35.983779+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2023-10-12T14:37:36.004707+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

this is my package.json:

```
          {
              "name": "moeezpetfinder",
              "version": "1.0.0",
              "description": "",
              "main": "index.js",
              "scripts": {
                  "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
                  "start": "node server/server.js"
              },
              "repository": {
                  "type": "git",
                  "url": "git+https://github.com/moeezramay/FindMyPetPk.git"
              },
              "keywords": [],
              "author": "",
              "license": "ISC",
              "bugs": {
                  "url": "https://github.com/moeezramay/FindMyPetPk/issues"
              },
              "homepage": "https://github.com/moeezramay/FindMyPetPk#readme"
          }
```