# Error loading resource from server: the server responded with 404 in heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, next.js, server, router

this is my code for server.js:

```
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");

const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const PORTS = process.env.PORT || 8080;
const cors = require("cors");
const router = express.Router();

router.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.send("Server is up!");
});
module.exports = router;
const sign = require("./apis/sign");

const upload = require("./apis/upload");

const KEY = "asfasfgasghhgewgwedsgawsdg";

app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());

//Redirects to signIn or SignUp Api's
app.use("/sign", sign);

//Redirects to upload for data submitting on found page
app.use("/upload", upload);

app.listen(PORTS, () => {
    console.log("Server started on port:", PORTS);
});
```

and these are my heroku logs:

```
2023-10-12T15:52:43.964164+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET 
path="/" host=pet-finder-1-6e4ec11ea0c6.herokuapp.com request_id=90a49113-fbf7-4b1b-bb18-ea7e00b81b35 
fwd="119.155.0.144" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=6ms status=404 bytes=415 protocol=https
```

here are some extra logs:

```
2023-10-12T15:52:47.983905+00:00 app[api]: Release v19 created by user moeezramay1@gmail.com
2023-10-12T15:52:47.983905+00:00 app[api]: Deploy f4d731b6 by user moeezramay1@gmail.com
2023-10-12T15:52:48.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2023-10-12T15:52:49.487848+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Restarting
2023-10-12T15:52:49.559516+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to starting
2023-10-12T15:52:50.138712+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2023-10-12T15:52:50.296191+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 143
2023-10-12T15:52:51.902264+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
```

I am using nextjs as front end and nodejs as backend, everything seems okay but i dont understand this error

Comment: Do you have the nodejs build pack added to your Heroku app? When you deploy, do you get a log showing NPM packages being installed for your app?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Deploying nextjs fronend and nodejs backend on heroku Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77281310/deploying-nextjs-fronend-and-nodejs-backend-on-heroku-error)

Comment: Also, can you please not ask multiple questions relating to the same issue. You already had a question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77281310/deploying-nextjs-fronend-and-nodejs-backend-on-heroku-error

Comment: i did add a build pack, after adding it this problem occured but it does not show dependencies being installed